# Purrr and Rlang - mapping functions with quasiquotation

Tags: r, purrr, rlang

If I have a function defined using rlang, how I can use purrr::map to use it with several variables ?

Suppose I have a function defined as:

```
mean_by <- function(data, by, var) {
  data %>%
    group_by({{ by }}) %>%
    summarise(avg = mean({{ var }}, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

Which computes group means,

Preferably using a purrr::map solution, how could I apply this function for several "by" variables but a single "var" in a data frame?

Answer (score 3):

You need the !!! operator or using group_by_at

```r
library(tidyverse)


mean_by <- function(data, by, var) {
  data %>%
    group_by_at(by) %>% 
    summarise(avg = {{var}} %>% mean(na.rm =TRUE))
}


mtcars %>% 
  mean_by(by = vars(mpg,cyl),hp)
#> # A tibble: 27 x 3
#> # Groups:   mpg [25]
#>      mpg   cyl   avg
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  10.4     8   210
#>  2  13.3     8   245
#>  3  14.3     8   245
#>  4  14.7     8   230
#>  5  15       8   335
#>  6  15.2     8   165
#>  7  15.5     8   150
#>  8  15.8     8   264
#>  9  16.4     8   180
#> 10  17.3     8   180
#> # … with 17 more rows


# or


mean_by <- function(data, by, var) {
  data %>%
    group_by(!!!by) %>% 
    summarise(avg = {{var}} %>% mean(na.rm =TRUE))
}


mtcars %>% 
  mean_by(by = vars(cyl,disp),hp)
#> # A tibble: 27 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>      cyl  disp   avg
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     4  71.1    65
#>  2     4  75.7    52
#>  3     4  78.7    66
#>  4     4  79      66
#>  5     4  95.1   113
#>  6     4 108      93
#>  7     4 120.     97
#>  8     4 120.     91
#>  9     4 121     109
#> 10     4 141.     95
#> # … with 17 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think the first option is probably better if you want to use vars() helpers

Answer (score 0):

A good alternative is to ["pass the dots"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-gknoyjL3A).

The first argument will be the single variable you want to summarise, and use `...` to pass all (if any) grouping variables you want.

This way you have a cleaner syntax for your function and you avoid including the `vars` function.

```r
library(tidyverse)


mean_by <- function(data, var, ...) {
  data %>%
    group_by(...) %>% 
    summarise(avg = {{var}} %>% mean(na.rm =TRUE))
}


mtcars %>% 
  mean_by(hp, cyl, disp)
#> # A tibble: 27 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>      cyl  disp   avg
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     4  71.1    65
#>  2     4  75.7    52
#>  3     4  78.7    66
#>  4     4  79      66
#>  5     4  95.1   113
#>  6     4 108      93
#>  7     4 120.     97
#>  8     4 120.     91
#>  9     4 121     109
#> 10     4 141.     95
#> # ... with 17 more rows


mtcars %>% 
  mean_by(hp)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>     avg
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  147.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>